# ajax responding page not responding

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a PHP program that uses AJAX but for some reason the update page (response text) is not responding. I cannot seem to find what wrong and any help will be greatly appreciated.

The  program simply goes into the database and gets a date from a field and uses AJAX to send it to the update page responsible for the response text. The update page then simply gets the date it was sent,gets the current and returns it to the original page that then displays both dates in an alert box.

ajax_test.php:

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <script>
      var tmr;// timer
      var xmlhttp;

      function UpdateTable()
      { 
           if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
           {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
           }
           else
           {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
           }

      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
           if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
           {
                var tokens = xmlhttp.responseText.split("|");
                alert(tokens[0]+",    "+tokens[1]);
           }
      }

      xmlhttp.open("GET","update_ajax_test.php?date1="+newDate,true);
      xmlhttp.send();   
 }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="tmr=setInterval(UpdateTable,5000)">
 <?php
      mysql_connect("xxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxx") or die("not logged in");
      //////now selecting our database
      mysql_select_db("xxxxxxxxx") or die(mysql_error());

      $res = mysql_query("SELECT num FROM table1");
      $numEnter=$_GET['name'];

      echo'<form method="get" action="ajax_test.php">';
      echo'  <input type="text" name="name"><br>';
      echo' <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"><br>';
      echo'</form>';

      date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
      $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
      echo $date;

      mysql_query("INSERT INTO table1(num,last_updated) VALUES ('$numEnter','$date')");

      echo"<table border=1 id='t1'>";
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
      {
           echo"<tr><td>";
           echo $row['num'];
           echo"</td></tr>";
      }
      echo"</table>";
 ?>
 <script>
      var newDate ;
      newDate=<? echo $date; ?>;
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

update_ajax_test.php

```
 <?php
 //////connecting to our sql server
 mysql_connect("xxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxx") or die("not logged in");
 //////now selecting our database
 mysql_select_db("xxxxxxxxx") or die(mysql_error());

 $former_page_date=$_GET['date1'];
 $query3=mysql_query("SELECT last_updated FROM table1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");

 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query3)){
      $update_page_date=$row['last_updated'];
 }////END WHILE

 echo $update_page_date;
 echo "|";
 echo $former_page_date;
 ?>
```

Comment: declare var xmlhttp as Global variable

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope
OP: Put "var" in front of the first assignments to xmlhttp in the if and else so that it's formally declared. Otherwise you need to declare it as a global

Comment: just added the var xmlhttp; as a global..still nothing...

Comment: what is the output of your code and what output you expected.?

Comment: @Zarazthuztra as you see he is using limit 1. so one record will be fetched

Comment: so you can say he has to use if instead of while.

Comment: @SatishSharma Totally didn't see that, my bad

Comment: output: the updated_ajax_test.php should return two tokens both date&times and the the ajax_test.php page will get the two returned tokens and display them in an alert from the ajax code in the function UpdateTable().